# Enet: How many consecutive connections can enet handle?

Tags: c++, networking, enet

I'm using Godot game engine to create a multiplayer game, it supports UDP, TCP and websockets. According to my research UDP is the only one reliable, they use Enet.

I didn't get a decisive answer from godot community on how many consecutive connections Enet can handle, many create a new server instance using docker per room, I don't like that

I want to have 8 players per room, how many consecutive connections can Enet handle before that I have to create a new  docker instance? If there's no good answer, I'd like to know the safest bet before creating an instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just asked Enet creator on github, a super nice guy, he replied very fast, Enet can handle 4k connections on a single host.

I quote:

"Trying to do more than 4K connections on a single host would not really be
that efficient, because you are stressing one single OS process trying to
deal with all the load of them. So you might want to reconsider your
networking architecture so that those connections get split over to
multiple hosts/servers and so they you can take advantage of parallelism."